# How to change the background of a sites body element to correspond with a slideshow?

Tags: javascript, css, background, slideshow

I'm a javascript newb and I was wondering if the following was possible:

I have a javascript slideshow which looks like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cycle.all.2.72v2.js.gz"></script> 
<script>
        $('#cycleLifestyle').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            timeout: 5000,
            pager: '#nav',
            pause: 'true'
        });
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#cycleLifestyle').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
        });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
        #cycleLifestyle {visibility:hidden;}
        #r1 {background:url(131112_FW_HP_R1.jpg) repeat-x top center; width:1000px; height:396px;}
        #r2 {background:url(131112_FW_HP_R2.jpg) no-repeat top center; width:1000px; height:396px;}
</style>
<div id="cycleLifestyle" style="position: relative; width: 1000px;">
    <div class="cycleLifestyle1">
        <div id="r1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cycleLifestyle2">
        <div id="r2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is to add some styling to the body of the page i.e. a background image, that changes depending on which rotation is being viewed.

So something along the lines of

```
if .cycleLifestyle1 opacity = 1 then
    use body{background:url(image.jpg)}
else
    use body{background:url(image2.jpg)}
```

But how would I write this and add it to the existing javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me.

```
<script>

        function onAfter() {
            var currentVisible = $('.cycleDiv:visible').attr('class').split(' ')[0];
            $('body').removeClass().addClass(currentVisible).fadeIn();
        }   

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#cycleLifestyle').cycle({
                fx: 'fade',
                timeout: 5000,
                pager: '#nav',
                pause: 'true',
                after: onAfter
            });
        });
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#cycleLifestyle').css('visibility', 'visible'); 
        });     

        </script>
<style type="text/css">
        .cycleLifestyle1 {
            background: url('images/image1.png') top center no-repeat #05387b;
        }
        .cycleLifestyle2 {
            background: url('images/image2.png') top center no-repeat #85152c;
        }
        body {
            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        }
        #r1 {background:url(image3.jpg) repeat-x top center; width:1000px; height:396px;}
        #r2 {background:url(image4.jpg) no-repeat top center; width:1000px; height:396px;}
        #cycleLifestyle {visibility:hidden;}
</style>
<div id="cycleLifestyle" style="position: relative; width: 1000px;">
    <div class="cycleLifestyle1">
        <div id="r1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cycleLifestyle2">
        <div id="r2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```
if($('.cycleLifestyle1').css('opacity') == 1){
    $('body').css('background', 'url:(image2.jpg)');
}else{
    $('body').css('background', 'url:(image1.jpg)');
}
```

Comment: Cheers dude. I'm sure this would have probably worked on any other website, but not mine, I don't know why. I've found an alternative solution which I'll post later. I also wanted to mark your answer as useful as I appreciate your help but unfortunately I don't yet have the privilege to use that feature.

Answer (score 0):

On what I have seen [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/after.html) jQuery.cycle has a callback after each animation.

```
jQuery('#cycleLifestyle').cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 5000,
    pager: '#nav',
    pause: 'true',
    after:   onAfter
});

function onAfter() {
    // get current visible div by opacity
    var currentDiv = jQuery('div.cycleDiv[style*="opacity: 1"]');

    if (currentDiv.hasClass('class1')) {
        jQuery('body').css('background', 'url:(image1.jpg)');
    }
    else if (currentDiv.hasClass('class2')) {
        jQuery('body').css('background', 'url:(image2.jpg)');
    }
    // and so on... 
}
```

Change all your div classes to currentDiv and add additional helper classes like 'class1', 'class2' and so on!

Hope I could help!

Comment: Cheers dude. I'm sure this would have probably worked on any other website, but not mine, I don't know why. I've found an alternative solution which I'll post later. I also wanted to mark your answer as useful as I appreciate your help but unfortunately I don't yet have the privilege to use that feature.